# use of undeclared identifier AND Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::ifstream;

map<string, string> buildMap(ifstream &map_file)
{
  map<string, string> trans_map;
  string key;
  string value;
  while (map_file >> key && getline(map_file, value))
      if (value.size() > 1)
          trans_map[key] = value.substr(1);
      else
          throw runtime_error("no rule for " + key);
  return trans_map;

}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the error is

```
 cppMapTest.cpp:19:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'runtime_error'
        throw runtime_error("no rule for " + key);
```

but when I add `using std::runtime_error;`,the error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~pair() in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "typeinfo for std::runtime_error", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void*>*) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void*>*) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__find_equal_key(std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      buildMap(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator>><char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void*>*) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~pair() in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in cppMapTest-1b8776.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I programme on mac terminal with vim,compiler is clang-`clang cppMapTest.cpp -o cppMapTest.exe`

I want to know why,thank you.

Comment: I have add "using std::runtime_error;",there is another error occur.Could you read it again?Anyway,thank you very much.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, compile using `clang++ cppMapTest.cpp -o cppMapTest.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

You already figured out how to avoid the `runtime_error` error (`using std::runtime_error;`).

The linker errors can be fixed by compiling with `clang++`.

When compiling with `clang`, your compiler only links against the C libraries, not the C++ ones.

Comment: oh,thank you very much!I'm a novice programmer and I really don't know about this.Thank you again.